# Intentionally collapsing long messages with Slack API

Tags: slack-api

I'm using the Slack API to send messages to channels using [blocks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts). Some of these messages consist of quite a few blocks and are quite long, occasionally reaching nearly a full vertical screenful. Normally, long messages are automatically collapsed by Slack with a button to expand the message, but these messages are not. I'm assuming this is due to the fact that they are made up of multiple blocks. Is there a way to trigger long messages made up of blocks to get collapsed?

Comment: I believe blocks are currently not collapsed, only attachments are.